# Opening table from file geodatabase in ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, file-geodatabase

I have tables in a file geodatabase. I want to open and work with them in my script. The first step I appear to have to do is scripted underneath. My result of this script is all names of all tables in my Geodatabase. I would like to also extract all data within these tables. So that I have a matrix or a list of lists in python.

Is this possible?

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env

env.workspace = r"D:\data\sre20821\Documents\Voorspelmodel\Geodatabases\2_Component.gdb"

datasetList = arcpy.ListTables("*")

for dataset in datasetList:
     print dataset
```

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//002z00000011000000

Comment: Why is it so damn hard to open a table from a Geodatabase in Arcpy. This should be a basic functionality. Its like nobody works with tables and arcpy.

Comment: Because arcpy is a poorly designed API. It's *certainly* not Pythonic. This is typical of ESRI APIs in my experience; they do not adopt the norms of the language's community or work to ensure the API is usable without a lot of hassle. I don't think they, as a company, see the need to. People are locked into ESRI because they start using it before the need for developer involvement arises (...although using from the GUI isn't *that* great of an experience, either).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a cursor to loop through each dataset and print each row.

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env

env.workspace = r"D:\data\sre20821\Documents\Voorspelmodel\Geodatabases\2_Component.gdb"

datasetList = arcpy.ListTables("*")

for dataset in datasetList:
     with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(dataset, "*") as cur:
          for row in cur:
              print row
```

see: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//018w00000011000000

Answer (score 1):

If you want to read tabular data into a dictionary for further analysis, you could try something like this...

```
import csv

for file in datasetList:
    n=open(file,'r') # opens the file
    reader=csv.DictReader(n,delimiter = ',') #or whatever your delimiter is
    data={} #initializes the dictionary
    for row in reader:
        # reads the data from your table into the dictionary
        for col,val in row.iteritems():
            data.setdefault(col,[]).append(val)
```

This assumes 'file' contains the full file path to the table in your gdb. Else you'll need to 'path+file' in the n=open call. The result will give you a dictionary (data) with table headers as keys. If this works you should be able to...

```
print list(data.keys()) # to view a list of your headers
```

Then you can index the data by...

```
data['key1'][0] # first value in column 'key1'
```

Dictionaries are good for beginners. If you are more comfortable with Python I highly recommend the [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) module for working with tabular data. It's very powerful and easy to use. Hope this helps!

Comment: It looks awesome and I think that the functionality is exactly what I need. My table is however not a CSV. I have created it within ArcGIS by "Create table". The line: n=open(file,'r') does not work for me.

Comment: Yeah I've never really worked with those types of tables. Are your data associated with a shapefile? Then you should access the shp's dbf file and resave as a csv.

Answer (score 1):

To read a table in a geodatabase to a NumPy Array you can use `arcpy.da.TableToNumPyArray(in_table, field_names)`. Specifying a list of field names is recommended for performance reasons, but you can use `'*'` for all fields. The resulting NumPy Array can be converted to a Pandas DataFrame.

```py
import arcpy
import pandas as pd

input = r'my_project.gdb\my_table'
arr = arcpy.da.TableToNumPyArray(input, '*')

# convert to a Pandas DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(arr)
```

For details, refer to Esri's [arcpy.da.TableToNumPyArray](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/data-access/tabletonumpyarray.htm) documentation.