FileNotFoundError on open() command on Standalone Table in ArcGIS Pro geodatabase
I am working on an areal interpolation question for which I have used the Tabulate Intersect function to print out a standalone table in my geodatabase named "Gr_TabulateInter". However, I have not been successfully able to open the standalone table using the standard commands I am familiar with:
Example 1
TabulatedIntersectionTable = open('Gr_TabulateInter')

prints out:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
In  [3]:
Line 3:     TabulatedIntersectionTable = open('Gr_TabulateInter')

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Gr_TabulateInter'
---------------------------------------------------------------------------


Using a full directory with the r or f prefix makes no difference. The original table was located in a .gdb on Onedrive, but moving it to a system folder made no difference.
Tables are clearly located within the directory, as seen in the following example:
Example 2
import csv

workspace=input(f"1. Enter the directory of your workspace: ")
arcpy.env.workspace = r'{}'.format(workspace)

datasetList = arcpy.ListTables("*")

print(datasetList)

for file in datasetList:
    n=open(file,'r') 

prints out
['SJ_Table', 'Point_ExportTable', 'Gr_TabulateInter']
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
In  [11]:
Line 11:    n=open(file,'r') 

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'SJ_Table'
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

Even other tables are failing to be read, so I'm not sure the solution to successfully reading tables stored in gdb.
My end goal is to use ArcPy and Pandas to generate a weighted average of class values per zone they lie inside, multiplying the sum_field values by the percentage they make up of the zone, then summing that number and dividing by 100 it to print out a sum_field value for the entire zone.

To read a file geodatabase table I would use arcpy.da.SearchCursor.

Welcome to GIS SE. Thank you for taking the Tour. "File geodatabase" is called that because it's in a bunch of files, not an RDBMS. But the tables within the .gdb folder are not ASCII files with the same name as the table. You can see that by just looking at the folder contents. In order to read the data, you need a FGDB-aware library (which stock Python is not). So if your goal is to use ArcPy and GeoPandas to read the data, you need to choose one and make an attempt, since just using open  doesn't make weight as a coding attempt here.

Thanks, with a bit more searching I was able to interpret how to use arcpy.da.SearchCursor through this separate question (https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/130240/opening-table-from-file-geodatabase-in-arcpy). I will follow up if there are any more issues.
